# File structure renaming in python

Tags: python

Hope someone could help me organize my thoughts on a project I’m working on. I’m currently trying to write a python script that will rename the names of tv shows in a specific format and order.

Say I have a file structure as follows,

```
Game of thrones
Season 1
   Episode 1ndjakchekzu.mkv
   Episode 2 mcndnsjhf.mkv
```

What I’m hoping to do is write a script that causes the file structure to look like this

```
`Game of Thrones
    Season 01
       Episode 01.mkv
       Episode 02.mkv
```

Any tips on organizing, tools to use or pre existing scripts would be incredibly helpful thanks.

import os,sys
`  i=1

#makes path the designated folder
#path = input("Enter the file folder path.")

#used for testing
path = "C:\Users\Desktop\Naruto"

```
#variable for extension
#extension = input("Enter the file type.")
 extension = ".avi"
#prints out original files in folder
 os.chdir(path)
 for file in os.listdir():
    src=file
    dst="e"+str(i).zfill(2) + extension
    os.rename(src,dst)
    i+=1
    print (os.listdir(path))
```

This is what i've got so far but it seems that when run it i'm losing episodes somewhere (start with 220 and end with 209) and that the episodes are out of order after renaming.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your question and include your code. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? What exactly are you struggling with? See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Finding a general solution is probably difficult.
My example extracts the episode number from the filename and uses it again.

```
import glob,os,re

path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/Naruto')
suff = '.avi'
length = 0

for src in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, f'*{suff}')):
    match = re.match(r'^Episode\s+(?P<num>\d+).*$', os.path.basename(src))
    if not match: raise Exception('missmatch found: {src!r}')
    length = max(length, len(match.group('num')))

for src in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, f'*{suff}')):
    match = re.match(r'^Episode\s+(?P<num>\d+).*$', os.path.basename(src))
    if not match: raise Exception('missmatch found: {src!r}')
    fname = f"ep_{match.group('num').zfill(length)}{suff}"
    dst = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(src), fname)
    os.rename(src, dst)
```